# How to write function that combines all the following to reach desired output

Tags: haskell

```
type Field = String
type Row = [Field]
type Column = [Field]
type Table = [Row]



print_line :: [Int] -> String
print_line lstcolumnwidths = case lstcolumnwidths of
    []      ->  "+"
    n:ns    -> '+' :replicate n '-' ++ print_line ns
```

This code creates a line eg. with an input [3,6] it will return "+---+------+"

```
print_field :: Int -> Field -> String
print_field columnwidth fieldcont 
    |isNum fieldcont        =  replicate (columnwidth - length fieldcont) ' ' ++ fieldcont
    |otherwise              = fieldcont ++ replicate (columnwidth - length fieldcont) ' '

isNum :: String -> Bool
isNum s = case s of 
     []      -> True
     x:xs    -> isDigit x && isNum xs
```

This code formats a Field eg input 5 "Amy" returns "Amy  " and 
for input 5 "78" returns "   78"

```
print_row :: [Int] -> Row -> String
print_row lstcolumnwidths lstfieldcont  = convertString (zipWith print_field 
lstcolumnwidths lstfieldcont)


convertString :: [String] -> String     
convertString x = case x of
    []      -> "|"
    x:xs    -> '|' : x ++ convertString xs
```

This code returns a formatted row eg input [5,4] ["Tommy","20" ] returns
"|Tommy|  20|"

```
print_table :: Table -> [String]
```

I want to write a function for this that takes a Table and returns a list of Fields.
The input will be

```
[["first","last","gender","age"],["Patricia","Davies","female","20"],
["Paul","Dowden","male","19"],["John","Doe","male","24"],
["David","Barker","male","21"],["Eve","Lee","female","23"],
["Mary","Hester","female","21"]]
```

and i want the output to be

```
 ["+--------+------+------+---+","|FIRST   |LAST    |GENDER|AGE","|Paul    
|Dowden  |male  | 19","+--------+------+------+---+","|David   |Barker  |male  | 21"...etc ]
```

Any tips on how to write a function that combines all the previous to reach this would be helpful.

I also have a function

```
convert :: String -> String
convert list = case list of
   []          -> []
   c:cs
     |isUpper c -> c: convert cs
     |otherwise -> toUpper c : convert cs
```

Which is used to convert the first field into uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have nearly everything in place.  All you seem to be missing is, first, a means to calculate the widths of the columns.  You can define:

```
colWidth :: Column -> Int
colWidth fields = maximum (map length fields)
```

to calculate the width of a single column.

Then, you can use `transpose` from `Data.List` to transpose your table from a list of rows into a list of columns and map `colWidth` over those columns:

```
colWidths :: Table -> [Int]
colWidths table = map colWidth (transpose table)
```

Second, you'll need the definition of `print_table`, which is short because you've already put in all the hard work:

```
print_table :: Table -> [String]
print_table table =
  let wdths = colWidths table              -- the column widths
      separator = print_line wdths         -- the row-by-row separator
      heading:body = map (print_row wdths) table   -- the rows
      heading' = convert heading           -- the heading in upper-case
  in [separator] ++ intersperse separator (heading':body) ++ [separator]
```

The only "trick" here is using `intersperse` (also from `Data.List`) to stick a copy of the separator between every pair of rows.